# Why does the program keep going?

Tags: matlab, function

Im just gonna skip the irrelevant parts of the code 
1)

```
function program()

choice=input('What is your choice?','s')
runProgram(choice)
disp('the program will now end')
```

In this function I am just supposed to type a number between 1 and 5

```
function runProgram(choice)

if choice==1
    loadfile
elseif.....
end
```

This function just determines which of the 5 subfunctions we will be running.

```
function loadfile()

filename=input('Write the name of the file here: ','s')
loadfile(filename)
```

where loadfile is another subfunction of this one, but I don't need to go in detail on that. Because right now my problem is this:
I run the 'program' function and type in a number, but then it just immediatly skip to the end message and the program ends. Shouldn't the program go through the subfunctions first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving input as string. So comparison fails.

Just use

```
input('What is your choice?')
```

without 's'

Answer (score 2):

Your `choice` variable is a String, but you're comparing it to an integer (`if choice==1`). You need to either compare it to a string (using `strcmp`) or convert it to a number (using `str2num`).